# MySQL: How to update a table using JOIN with another table, based on row sequence?

Tags: mysql

The following is the setup code:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table2;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table1 (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `doc_no` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `other_table_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table2 (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `doc_no` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO temp_table1 (doc_no)
VALUES ('100/1/23-24'), ('100-1-2324');

INSERT INTO temp_table2 (id, doc_no)
VALUES (101, '10012324'), (102, '100/1/2324'), (103, '100/1-23/24');


SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

Here, I have deliberately given similar (but not exactly equal) values for `doc_no` in all the rows of both the tables.

Now, coming to the question:

I want to `UPDATE` each row of `temp_table1` with the `id` of each row of `temp_table2` based on the row sequence and based on the other matching conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

For example, update row 1 of `temp_table1` with the id of row 1 of `temp_table2` i.e. `101`, update row 2 of `temp_table1` with the id of row 2 of `temp_table2` i.e. `102`, and so on wherever the `doc_no` matches after removing the special characters.

As you can see, `temp_table2` has 1 extra row, that row's id should not go anywhere in `temp_table1`.

If I run:

```
UPDATE temp_table1 T0
INNER JOIN temp_table2 T1
ON RemoveSpecialCharacters(T0.doc_no) = RemoveSpecialCharacters(T1.doc_no)
SET T0.other_table_id = T1.id;
```

then, the output in `temp_table1` is:

```
id  doc_no      other_table_id
1   100/1/23-24 101
2   100-1-2324  101
```

whereas, required output is:

```
id  doc_no      other_table_id
1   100/1/23-24 101
2   100-1-2324  102
```

In short, when multiple rows of temp_table1 match with multiple rows of temp_table2, I want to match them based on row sequence.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: a [data retrieval problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77706928/do-probable-match-of-rows-in-2-similar-mysql-tables) disguised with `UPDATE`. op is not transparent in regard to the core of the problem.

Comment: Probably you are not able to comprehend the question

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution using [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to check the order of the row. Unfortunately we can't utilize Window Function directly inside Update statement hence we need a "reference list." The following query creates reference list called `temp_joined` for the role.

```
WITH temp2_numbered AS
   (
     SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER()
         OVER (PARTITION BY
               RemoveSpecialCharacters(T.doc_no)
               ORDER BY T.id
   ) AS rc
    FROM temp_table2 AS T),
   temp1_numbered AS
   (
     SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER()
         OVER (PARTITION BY
               RemoveSpecialCharacters(T.doc_no)
               ORDER BY T.id
    ) AS rc
    FROM temp_table1 AS T),
    temp_joined AS
    (
      SELECT T0.id AS T0id, T1.id AS T1id
      FROM temp1_numbered AS T0
        LEFT JOIN temp2_numbered AS T1
        ON RemoveSpecialCharacters(T0.doc_no)
           = RemoveSpecialCharacters(T1.doc_no)
        AND T0.rc = T1.rc
    )
UPDATE temp_table1 AS T0
LEFT JOIN temp_joined AS T1
   ON T0.id
      = T1.T0id
SET T0.other_table_id = T1.T1id;
```

This will output:

| id | doc_no | other_table_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100/1/23-24 | 101 |
| 2 | 100-1-2324 | 102 |

There are some gotchas to the solution. For one, if `temp_table1` has more row than `temp_table2` then it gives you `null`. The solution also only works on [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) 8+. There might be a better way to solve the problem.

See fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9BFhvFou6cbKzdNZRbbWZU/0

Comment: Alright, but the actual UPDATE query has WHERE condition on 5 columns, and there are about 40-50 such queries, each updating the same table and using join on the same set of tables, but using a different WHERE condition in each UPDATE query. And this is not a one-off task. Is there any alternate solution? Otherwise, I will need to create 40-50 such huge queries and speed / performance is definitely a consideration here, because it is triggered by user on demand.

Comment: Basically, this is one of several probable match conditions, and this is related to my other query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77706928/do-probable-match-of-rows-in-2-similar-mysql-tables

Comment: @AllSolutions so, this question is basically a dupe with the other one? thats not very nice of you. to be honest, your entire idea to use "row sequence" in any way will make stuff slow reason being it need to traverse entire table. furthermore, the table is so denormalized and require a bunch overhead for the matching. put a bounty for better exposure, use that 1k+ rep.

Comment: @AllSolutions i saw you said "probable" match, if this process often done in quick succession then what you need is to either normalize the table or use external indexer that work best with text to process the data rather than abusing temporary tables.

Comment: this question is not at all a duplicate of the other question, although it is part of the same overall problem that I am trying to solve

Comment: How is normalizing the table going to help. The data in the 2 tables is from 2 different sources prepared by 2 different people, and probable match is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to compare stuff in row_number, you might want to add that column to temp_table1

```
ALTER TABLE temp_table1 ADD COLUMN R INT NULL;

-- The `old` (before 8.0) way to initialize the new column:
SET @i:=0; 
UPDATE temp_table1  SET R=(@i:=@i+1);

CREATE FUNCTION RemoveSpecialCharacters(s VARCHAR(45)) RETURNS VARCHAR(45) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(s,'/',''),'-','');
END;

SELECT * FROM temp_table1;
  
UPDATE temp_table1 t1
INNER JOIN (select *, row_number() over (order by id) as R 
               from temp_table2) t2 on t1.R=t2.R
                                   and RemoveSpecialCharacters(t1.doc_no) = RemoveSpecialCharacters(t2.doc_no)
SET other_table_id = t2.id
```

The result is:

| id | doc_no | other_table_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100/1/23-24 | 101 |
| 2 | 100-1-2324 | 102 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wdx2t1F_)